# Como retornar una lista en ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, postman

he creado un proyecto ASP.NET Core en web API , en mi controller estoy tratando de listar mis usuarios pero me da un error, la lista de usuarios esta en mi controller solo he agregado dos usuarios ¿ en que estoy fallando? ¿ esta bien crear mi lista de usuarios en mi controller?

este es mi controlador

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Project001.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace Project001.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<UserController>
        [HttpGet("lista")]
        public ActionResult listaUsuarios(int id)
        {
            var usuarios = from user in users()
                           where user.id.Equals(id)
                           select user;
            return (ActionResult)usuarios;
        }

        [NonAction]
        public List<User> users()
        {
            return new List<User>
            {
                new User
                {
                    id=1,
                    nombre="juan",
                    apellido="torres",
                    numero=12345
                },
                new User
                {
                    id=2,
                    nombre="pepe",
                    apellido="luna",
                    numero=678910
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

este es el error que me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos C Aldair, por lo que veo, eres nuevo en ASP.net Core, hace un tiempo hice un workshop de 4 horas explicando el panorama de ASP.net MVC, si bien es cierto, hay cambios en el código, pero la estructura es la misma, al igual que los conceptos, te invito a revisar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Espero sea de tu agrado :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes de envolver el resultado en un método que te devuelva un ObjectResult, Como lo es el Metodo `Ok()`, te quedaría algo así:

```
return Ok(usuarios.ToList());
```